# class objects in list all have the same last added value

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to learn Python,
I'm trying to make a class representing a whole deck of card.
so when creating the instance it should generate a list with cards.
The card represented with an object “Card” as well.

The problem is when I generate the cards by appending them to a list, all the items get overwritten by the last input

My code should generate 2 of Spades all the way to King of Spades. When printing it - 13 lines of King of Spades are printed.

What am I missing?

Here is my card class:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, color, cvalue):
        if color.lower() == "s":
            self.color = "Spades"
        elif color.lower() == "h":
            self.color = "Hearts"
        elif color.lower() == "d":
            self.lower = "Diamond"
        else:
            self.lower = "Clubs"
        if cvalue.isnumeric():
            Card.value = int(cvalue)
            if cvalue == '11':
                Card.card_name = 'Ace'
            else:
                Card.card_name = cvalue
        else:
            Card.value = 10
            if cvalue.lower() == 'j':
                Card.card_name = "Jack"
            elif cvalue.lower() == 'q':
                Card.card_name = "Queen"
            else:
                Card.card_name = "King"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{Card.card_name} of {self.color}'
```

This is the DeckOfCards class definition:

```
class DeckOfCards():
    deck = []
    def __init__(self):
        for x in range(2,12):
        DeckOfCards.deck.append(Card('s', str(x)))
        DeckOfCards.deck.append(Card('s', 'j'))
        DeckOfCards.deck.append(Card('s', 'q'))
        DeckOfCards.deck.append(Card('s', 'k'))
```

This is the test code to show the cards

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Card('s','11')
    d = DeckOfCards()
    for x in d.deck:
        print(x)
```

Comment: welcome! first of all, you have an error in the `__init__` of your `Card` class. when trying to assign `color` attribute to Diamond.

Comment: You are mixing class attributes (`Card.`) with instance attributes (`self.`) all over the place

Comment: You have both `self.lower = "Diamond"` and `self.lower = "Clubs"` when it should be `self.color = ...`

Comment: got it, I changed Card to self and it solved the problem